# Morphing 2 faces images

Tags: image, image-processing, opencv

I would like some help from the aficionados of openCV here.

I would like to know the direction to take (and some advices or piece of code) on how to morph 2 faces together with a kind of ratio saying 10% of the first and 90% of the second.

I have seen functions like cvWarpAffine and cvMakeScanlines but I am not sure how to use them.

So if somebody could help me here, I'll be very grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the images compared are the exact same images, you would not go very far with this.

This is an artificial intelligence problem and needs to be solved as such. Typical solution involves:

1. Normalising the data (removing noise, skew, ...) from the images
2. Feature extraction (turn the image into a smaller set of data)
3. Use a machine learning (typically classifiers) to train the data with your matches
4. Test the result
5. Refine previous processes according to the results until you get good recognition

The choice of OpenCV functions used depends on your feature extraction method. Have a look at [Eigenface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenface).

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer. I thought I've seen a piece of code doing morphing without any AI

Comment: You are right about that. There are plenty of examples that don't use machine learnine. e.g.: https://github.com/kallaballa/Poppy